# dataweave 2.0 csv transformattion

Tags: csv, dataweave, mulesoft

Getting below csv file as intput

```
Id|Name|ParentId
001|National|AREG-001
0013|Texas|AREG-001
0012|Tennessee|AREG-001
0006|Indiana|AREG-001
```

and I want output as

```
('001','National','AREG-001'),
('0013','Texas','AREG-001'),
('0012','Tennessee','AREG-001'),
('0006','Indiana','AREG-001')
```

**Runtime: 4.2.1**

how to transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quick and simple way of solving it.

```
output text/plain
---
"('" ++ 
(
  payload map ((value, index) -> 
    dw::core::Objects::valueSet(value) joinBy  "','"
  ) joinBy "'),\n('"
) 
++ "')"
```

Don't forget to set the CSV reader param `separator="|"` so the input is properly interpreted.

From Mule 4.3 and on, you can use `valuesOf` instead of `dw::core::Objects::valueSet`

Comment: 'valuesOf' is Introduced in DataWeave 2.3.0. Supported by Mule 4.3 and later, but current I'm using Runtime 4.2.1

Comment: the above transformation works. And i want to add "INSERT INTO" string to each one, which look like, 

`INSERT INTO ('ASC-AREG-001','Ascension National','');
INSERT INTO ('','Ascension Texas','ASC-AREG-001');
INSERT INTO ('ASC-MMKT-0012','','ASC-AREG-001');
INSERT INTO ('ASC-MMKT-0006','Ascension Indiana','ASC-AREG-001');`

Comment: transformation for above ask:                                                                                   
`output text/plain
var data='insert into'
---
"('" ++
(
  payload map ((value, index) ->
    dw::core::Objects::valueSet(value) joinBy  "','"
  ) joinBy "');\n ('"
)
++ "')" replace "('" with (data ++ "('")`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it using reduce() and concatenating explicitly each field:

```
%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---
payload  reduce ((item, acc = "") -> acc ++ "('" ++ item.Id ++ "','" ++ item.Name ++ "','" ++ item.ParentId ++ "')\n")]]></ee:set-payload>
```

In any case this is concatenating strings so you should be mindful that if the number of records is high you might run out of memory.

Comment: Getting below issue while transforming                                                                                    `You called the function '++' with these arguments: 
  1: String ("('")
  2: Null (null)
But it expects one of these combinations:
  (Array, Array)
  (Date, Time)
4| payload  reduce ((item, acc = "") -> acc ++ "('" ++ item.Id ++ "','" ++ item.Name ++ "','" ++ item.ParentId ++ "')\n")
   Trace:
  at main::++ (line: 4, column: 109)
  at main::++ (line: 4, column: 42)`

Comment: Looks like the payload is not parsed as CSV. Are you settling the right mime type for it?

Comment: adding flow: <flow name="prepare-sql" doc:id="2896a" ><file:listener doc:name="On New or Updated File" doc:id="3a19bfa" config-ref="File_Config" directory="/Users/Documents/temp2" autoDelete="true" outputMimeType="application/csv; separator=|" ></file:listener>
<ee:transform doc:name="Transform Message-each-field" doc:id="0073d2a1" >
<ee:message ><ee:set-payload ><![CDATA[%dw 2.0
output text/plain
---payload  reduce ((item, acc = "") -> acc ++ "('" ++ item.Id ++ "','" ++ item.Name ++ "','" ++ item.ParentId ++ "')\n")]]></ee:set-payload></ee:message></ee:transform></flow>

Comment: It's hard to read a flow in a comment but it looks like the header directive is missing in the mime type. Otherwise DataWeave can not match the field names to the headers in the CSV, then item.Id, etc return null, which seems to be what is mentioned in the error. Try changing it to `outputMimeType="application/csv;separator='|'; header=true"`